# Multiple Table through Join

Tags: sql, join

I have Three Tables 1. ItemMaster 2. GRN  3. Issue

```
Item Master
------------------
ItemCode          ItemDescr
--------          ---------
1                 Test1
2                 Test2
3                 Test3
4                 Test4
5                 Test5

GRN Table
-------------------
ItemCode          grnQty
--------         --------
1                 1
1                 2
2                 1
1                 2
2                 1
3                 1

Issue Table

ItemCode         issQty
--------         -------
1                 1
1                 2
2                 1
4                 1
```

I want to generate a report/view like ->

```
ItemCode          ItemDescr      GRN Qty      Issue Qty  
--------          ---------      -------      ---------         
1                  Test1          5              3                 
2                  Test2          2               1                 
3                  Test3          1               0
4                  Test4          0               1
5                  Test5          0               0
```

For this I have used the following sql code:

```
select a.ItemCode, a.ItemDescr, isnull(sum(b.grnQty),0) as 'GRN Qty', isnull(sum(c.issQty),0) as 'Issue Qty' from
ItemMaster a
left join GRN b
on a.ItemCode=b.ItemCode
left join Issue c
on a.ItemCode=c.ItemCode
group by a.ItemCode, a.ItemDescr
```

But the report generated is

```
ItemCode          ItemDescr      GRN Qty      Issue Qty  
--------          ---------      -------      ---------         
1                  Test1          10              9                 
2                  Test2          2               2                 
3                  Test3          1               0
4                  Test4          0               1
5                  Test5          0               0
```

What is wrong with my code???

It may be just a coincident that GRN Qty 10=5 X ( no of rows in Issue table for Item code 1) and same for other values like Issue qty 9 =3 X ( no of rows in GRN table for Item code 2)

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

No concidence here, what you describe is exactly your problem. Please look at the result of the simplified query:

```
select a.ItemCode, a.ItemDescr, b.grnQty as 'GRN Qty', c.issQty as 'Issue Qty' 
from ItemMaster a
left join GRN b on a.ItemCode=b.ItemCode
left join Issue c on a.ItemCode=c.ItemCode
```

This table will look like (just the lines for ItemCode=1):

```
ItemCode          ItemDescr      GRN Qty      Issue Qty  
--------          ---------      -------      ---------         
1                  Test1         1            1                 
1                  Test1         2            1                 
1                  Test1         2            1                 
1                  Test1         1            2                 
1                  Test1         2            2                 
1                  Test1         2            2
```

Now add your group by + summing end you end up where you are.

So you cannot do the sums directly over a select with both joins, because you end up with all permutations of the joins.

So subqueries can be of help here:

```
select 
    a.ItemCode, 
    a.ItemDescr, 
    (select sum(b.grnQty) from GRN b where a.ItemCode=b.ItemCode) as 'GRN Qty', 
    (select sum(c.issQty) from Issue c where a.ItemCode=c.ItemCode) as 'Issue Qty' 
from ItemMaster a
```

Comment: Oh.. Thanks a lot. Xie, Man u are spot on.. I was coding for the whole day today, absolutely drained out.. missed it completely.. It is very well explained and I believe It is the solution I was looking for.. I will test it tomorrow and let you know..My actual script is way complex than this..I will test the theory from your answer and let u know..... Thank man... Regards Bhaskar